# extjs json decode

Tags: php, ajax, json, extjs

```
 function symbol_handler(){
   fp.getForm().submit({
     url:'/index.php/ajax/test_function',
       success:function(resp){
       //how would i access attributes of the json object?
     }
 });
```

edit: here is the php controller, in case it is relevant.

```
 function test_function(){
 $array = array(
    'success' => 'true',
    'msg' => 'testing testing testing'
    );
  echo json_encode($array);
```

}

output of console.log(resp) with

```
    function symbol_handler(){
     fp.getForm().submit({
         url:'/index.php/ajax/test_function',
         success:function(resp){
            console.log(resp);
         }
     });
   }
```

...

```
Object
activeAction: null
bodyStyle: "padding: 6px"
buttons: Array (1)
0: Object
handler: function symbol_handler(){
hideParent: true
minWidth: 75
removeMode: "container"
text: "GO"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array
el: Object
events: Object
frame: true
height: 100
id: "ext-gen48"
items: Object
labelWidth: 40
title: "Exercising textfields"
width: 300
__proto__: Object
```

Thanks, brandon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of the `success`-callback is `function(form, action)` where `form` is a reference to the form being submitted and `action` is the action object that has been submitted. It's either an instance of [`Ext.form.Action.Submit`](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.Action.Submit) or [`Ext.form.Action.DirectSubmit`](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.Action.DirectSubmit) (depending on whether you used `Ext.direct`).
The `action` object gives access to a plenty of properties, among those is the `result`-property that contains the decoded response object. So, your ExtJS code should look like:

```
function symbol_handler(){
   fp.getForm().submit({
       url:'/index.php/ajax/test_function',
       success:function(form, action){
          console.log(action.result);
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

according to the [extjs 3.2.1 API](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.Action.Submit#Ext.form.Action-success) (i don't know which version you are using), the  success function is passed the following parameters:

> 1. form : Ext.form.BasicForm The form
>      that requested the action
> 2. action : Ext.form.Action The Action class. The result property of
>      this object may be examined to
>      perform custom postprocessing.

Try to add the following to the success function to know what arguments are passed in the function:

```
console.log(arguments);
```